# Unable to create usable proxy of a Response object

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to create a proxy of a Response object, in hopes of ultimately overriding the behavior of a function.

The proxy object doesn't seem to work at all, even with an empty handler.

```
// Simple fetch, works fine
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => console.log(response.status));
    
// Fetch with proxy, fails
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => new Proxy(response, {}))
    .then(proxy => console.log(proxy.status));
```

The error is

> TypeError: 'get status' called on an object that does not implement interface Response.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to get it to work?